# Get field names of a class in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to generate a CSV mapping for the fields of a class in Java in an automatic way since I need to use it several times.

I have the following method for trying to get the field names: (where CSV header is something like "DB_NAME|FIELD_NAME|ADDITIONAL_F1|ADDITIONAL_F2")

```
package util;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CsvAttributesMappingGenerator {
public static String generateCsvAttributesMapping(Class<?> model) {

    StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Field[] fieldList = model.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fieldList) {
        //field.setAccessible(true);
        csvBuilder.append(field.getName().replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper})", "$1_$2").toUpperCase());
        csvBuilder.append("|");
        csvBuilder.append(field.getName());
        csvBuilder.append("||\n");
    }
    return formatOutput(csvBuilder.toString());
}

private static String formatOutput(String classText) {
    String delimiter = "\n******************************\n";
    return String.format("%s%s%s", delimiter, classText, delimiter);
}
```

}

and a test call like:

```
import objects.User;
import org.junit.Test;
import util.CsvAttributesMappingGenerator;

public class CsvAttributesMappingGeneratorTest {

@Test
public void testGenerationWithObject() {
    System.out.println(CsvAttributesMappingGenerator.generateCsvAttributesMapping(User.class));
}
}
```

The object to be parsed has the following structure:
    package objects;

```
public class User {
private String userName;
private String userEmail;
private int userAge;
private String otherDetails;
// getters, setters and all args constuctor here
}
```

The output should have multiple rows like FIELD_NAME|fieldName|| where the camel cased item should be collected from the given class. I attempted to use Java Reflection API as I have seen on several examples but I get a strange String output instead. (not the serialized @randomCharsLikeName). Tried toString() and other dirty tricks but nothing worked.

Can someone tip me up a little with this? Or at least tell me if it is possible to do what I tried?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** the current code prototype presented in the question works in an isolated environment (separate new project) and displays the expected output. It does not work though integrated within the whole application I am trying to integrate it into. I will keep researching and let you know the root cause (in the real app I am using also lombok for the classes (

> @AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor, @Data, @ToString

), but I do not honestly think that this might be an issue while using Reflection)

Comment: usage of the reflection is a proper way but you didn't point out the problem of your experience, so it's hard to pronounce the problem you had faced in

Comment: " but I get a strange String output instead" can you explain? and show what you exactly are getting and what you are expecting to get

Comment: well, actually instead of getting the field names, with the getName() method I get strange other String output

Comment: but explain what you are seeing here, "Strange" does not tell us anything useful, show examples, show us class that you are passing to this `generateCsvAttributesMapping` mehod, etc.

Comment: What does your formatOutput-method look like? It's the one that produces the end result.

Comment: also this `field.setAccessible(true);` does nothing in this code

Comment: Let me re-prototype this with a full working example set, I will edit the post ASAP answering your questions raised above.

Comment: Regarding the strange output, I did an update from SVN and the whole project and classpath need a fix in order to re-produce the wrong result in the real application (since it works fine in the isolated environment), I will be back with the wrong output I receive in this situation. @GotoFinal you were right, the field.setAccessible(true); is not doing anything. In the isolated environment it produces the correct output with/without that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the meanwhile. While I was play-prototyping the generator, I used:

```
csvBuilder.append(field.getClass().getName().replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper})", "$1_$2").toUpperCase());
```

which produced outputs like `JAVA.LANG.REFLECT._FIELD|java.lang.reflect.Field||`

Since I simply forgot that I actually improved it to use actual class object as a parameter to the function. Before asking the question I made some Sonar fixes to the code and did not notice that I fixed a WARN to remove the `.getClass()` method invocation since I already pass in a class (I thought it would not make a difference since it is just a warning). ***Moral tip of the day - NEVER EVER ignore warnings.***

So the code snippets presented in the question work fine now in an isolated dummy project and also integrated within a more complex project, using the fixed line:

```
csvBuilder.append(field.getName().replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper})", "$1_$2").toUpperCase());
```

Also as someone suggested in the comments, the `field.setAccessible(true);` can be removed since it is useless for the purpose of the method.

Comment: As important not to ignore warning, is not to hit the automatic fix button without understanding what the warning is about and what implications the change will have. By the way, I’d rather use `.replaceAll("([^_\\p{Lu}])(\\p{Lu})", "$1_$2").toUpperCase()`, to handle non-ASCII characters correctly and not to insert a `_` after a character that was already an uppercase letter or `_`, think of, e.g. `targetURL` or `scale_X`. And I don’t think that `String.format("%s%s%s", delimiter, classText, delimiter)` is more readable than `delimiter + classText + delimiter`…

Comment: Oh, I will give a try to the suggested improvement for the regexp... and yes I made a huge mistake by neglecting the warning and blindly fixing it. Regarding the String.format... it was rather used to avoid + on immutable strings, or the use of StringBuilder just to put together on the console 3 Strings. That format just made it easier to highlight in the console the generated content. I will let you know of the results with the improvement you proposed.

Comment: You know that `String.format` uses a `StringBuilder` internally? Its costs are always higher than a plain string concatenation via `+`. Before Java 9, both basically do the same thing with a `StringBuilder`, but `String.format` has to parse the format string first. Starting with Java 9, concatenation via `+` will become even more efficient.

Comment: I was actually unaware of that, but now that you mention it I will research it further. Anyway regarding the StringBuilder, I did not wanted to avoid this one because I particularly found it bad, just because I did not want to explicitly use it. Anyway + 3 Strings as you initially proposed would not have been a crime. It is just that I usually try to make get better practices when manipulating Strings (still learning).

Comment: Oh, I did not know about Java 9 optimizations and the other stuff you mentioned earlier. I "grew" up with SE 6 and 7.. recently started newer projects with 8. And everyone used to tell me during my development phase that it is better to avoid concatenating Strings with +. I will research this matter further since I believe that smaller improvements like this count in bigger applications. I will return with material and docs when I will find all the details you've mentioned. Or better if you have some further reading I am eager to find out more.

Comment: Even under Java 6 and 7, there rarely was a need to use `StringBuilder` explicitly. Before Java 9, string concatenation via `+` got compiled to use a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes anyway. Using a `StringBuilder` manually might be useful when appending in a loop or have to combine it with other string manipulation operations. Starting with Java 9, the actual implementation is left to the runtime. It may again use a `StringBuilder`, but could also use even more efficient code using implementation specific internal APIs. I know, there are a lot of “good advices” worth  an actual fact-check…